# How to handle Outage images in Azure WebApp

Tags: asp.net, azure, continuous-deployment, azure-web-app-service

We are hosting our website in Azure. During the deployment(TFS) we will do the below Steps as the part of the deployment pipeline.

1. Stop the WebApp
2. Deploy Web App Service
3. Start the WebApp

After the 1st step, if anyone tries to access our website, then by default Azure will return the below page

[image]

We really don't want our users to show this page during the outage. We are planning to show our own outage image/page in such case.

Is there is any way to achieve this?

Since Azure Web Apps in a Paas model, I'm wondering how to do this?

Any inputs Appreciated!

Comment: You can have two deployment slots, one for staging and the other one for production; then you can run your pipeline on your staging slot, aand when everything is ok with your deployment, just do an slot swap between staging and prod and then you are done...you can check the following article https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2017/05/16/deploy-app-azure-app-service/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it does **not suppport** custom error page at this time. There is [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/9912714-enable-users-to-create-custom-error-pages-for-403) on Enabling users to create custom error pages for 403 and 503 service unavailable messages.

I think you could up vote to promote the realization of this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Putting some additional information regarding the solution for my own question here,

*[Just found the OP in SO where the feedback originated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32762540/7073340)*

> There are two categories of HTTP errors that can happen on Azure Web
>   Apps:
>
> 1. Those that happen in IIS on the Web Worker where your site is running.
> 2. Those that happen before it reaches that. This includes cases when the
>      site is stopped, in the process of restarting, or potentially affected
>      by some other issue in the system. One way to tell if an error is #1
>      or #2 is to turn on http logging, and see if it gets logged. Only #1
>      will.
>
> For #1, you can customize errors using standard techniques. But for For #2, there is currently no way for you to customize the pages returned by Azure.

Thanks, [@David Ebbo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/111888/david-ebbo) and [@SamJolly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2038271/samjolly)