# App_offline.htm for Azure WebSite running Java not working

Tags: java, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a tomcat site running on Azure WebSite using the httpPlatform setting on the web.config file.

I have already created a file called "app_offline.htm" which is supposed to be shown when I stop and start my app, but it is never shown.

Is there a way in this scenario to provide a static page while the httpPlatform handler is loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is absolutely not. While you did the stop or restart operation for your website in Azure portal, the IIS and/or its `httpPlatform` handler will really stop working, so there is not a HTTP service can help responsing any pages in your website.

When an Azure Website stoped, only one page will be responsed by Azure which is `Error 403 - This web app is stopped.` as below.

[image]

But it can not be customised, due to the reason #2 which has been answered by Azure Team member at the SO thread [How to customise Azure Web App 403, 503 error pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32760302/how-to-customise-azure-web-app-403-503-error-pages).

Per my experience, a workaround way is that to use a reverse proxy to check your website whether be alive and response your `app_offline` page, such as Nginx module `ngx_http_upstream_check_module` and to define `error_page 403=301 /your-403-app_offline.html;`.