# How to customize default error pages in azure web app for linux?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I have hosted .NET core 3.1.1 LTS app in Azure web app for linux? How do I customize default error pages like 
1. 502
2 Error pages when app service is stopped. 
3 Error page when app is being published from Visual studio , VS code / FTP

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to customise Azure Web App 403, 503 error pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32760302/how-to-customise-azure-web-app-403-503-error-pages)

Comment: There is request for this on Azure Feedback. I think if there will be enough up votes they will make it this possible: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/9912714-enable-users-to-create-custom-error-pages-for-403

Comment: Hi, Bharat. Is my answer useful to you?

Comment: @jason - No, I am looking for linux web app service without app gateway. For app gateway azure charges some more amount.

Comment: I have modified my answer, you can try it. @Bharat

Answer (score 0):

I find a docs about creating Application Gateway custom error pages,maybe it's good for you. [custom error pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/custom-error)
How to create custom error page in code.

*We also can handle it by code.Here is my suggest.*

**Errors like 500, we can handle it by filter**,

```
public class ErrorPageFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode == 500)
        {
            context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("error/500");
        }
        base.OnResultExecuted(context);
        }
}

[ErrorPageFilter]
public abstract class PageController
{}
```

For .netcore mvc project, it also comes with pipeline processing for error pages when it is created.

In startup.cs,

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
        //dev env show error page
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            //prod env show custom page
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }
}

//In HomeController has this function,
//You just replace cshtml file by you want
[ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore =     true)]
public IActionResult Error()
{
    return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ??     HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
}
```

**Errors like 404, we can**,

In startup.cs file find configure function,then add below code,

```
  app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/error/{0}");
```

Then add error Controller,

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
        /// <summary>
        /// In content in {0} is error code
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [Route("/error/{0}")]
        public IActionResult Page()
        {
            //Jump to 404 error page
            if (Response.StatusCode == 404)
            {
                return View("/views/error/notfound.cshtml");
            }
            return View();
        }
}
```

Pay attention, if use ErroeController( handle 404 error), pls don't use
`app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error")`, 
you just need handle error in Controller.

Comment: Documented pointed out uses app gateway. How can this be done without using application gateway?

Comment: Ok, I know. I will modify my answer to help you. About how to custom error pages in .net core programs.

Comment: You can try it,  if it works or not, pls let me know.@Bharat

Comment: partially problem is solved for 404, 403 by using status code pages as you suggested. But still I am yet to figure out how to customize azure default pages like 502, error when app is being published from vs web deploy

Comment: Do you try to use this way which code like  `context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode == 500` ?  You  can modify `StatusCode` and track it.